# How to remove batch of points in the period based on xAxis(time) coordinates from the series in Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a series and I need to remove points selected by time.
For example points from 4 Dec to 25 Dec in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9rLbft5q/

```
series: [{
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: data,
    type: 'areaspline',
    threshold: null,
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
    }
}]
```

Comment: It is possible to update series data after loading chart using Series.update() and Series.setData() methods. With this methods you can filter existing data and update chart with new set of your points. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9rLbft5q/13/

Answer (score 1):

Filter data retrieved from `getJson()` with [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var start = new Date("4 Dec 2017").getTime();
var end = new Date("25 Dec 2017").getTime();
var filtered = data.filter(function(item, index, arr) {
  if (item[0]>end || item[0]<start) return item;
}, []);
```

Check fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/axxm0fh1/

Comment: It looks like your method shows how not how to delete, but how not to get. I have the dynamically updated series and I need old points to be removed once in couple minutes. Highcharts' 'shift' function doesn't suit me too. So I need a method that will remove points 'from' and 'to' the specified time.

Comment: `filtered` array contains only data matching to filter criteria (inner function), so the points are "deleted" from origina `data` array.

Comment: I don't understand if you need to remove points after having created the chart...